# How to return raw string after calling an API (not json-formatted nor xml-formatted, just raw string)

Tags: php, rest, api, soap, magento2

Calling the REST API or the SOAP API will format the returned string to respectively JSON and XML.

However I need the string returned by the service method to be a raw string, with no formatting whatsoever.

The reason behind that is that the service's method calls a legacy model that returns a complex response ; and this response should be transmitted as-is, without any formatting.

Comment: I would be more than happy to give further details to specify the question, if needed.

Comment: A REST API will only response with JSON if the owner adds support for that. It could return any content type that they choose.

Maybe you want an API that returns `plain/text`?

Comment: That is totally correct

Comment: So, do you have a question, or is this resolved?

Comment: That is an excellent clue, I shall extend   \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\RendererInterface and inject it into a Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response (or just extend Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response).

Comment: https://gielberkers.com/add-custom-renderer-webapi-magento-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this *dirty* solution:

```
exit('raw text message');
```

This by passes Magento's JSON wrapper, and echoes directly the wanted text.